# Turn MySQL CHAR(1) columns into TINTINT

Tags: mysql

As a lead-in, I'd like to say I'm a heck of a PHP programmer--and no better versed in SQL than that role requires.

I have inherited a table with a legacy structure that uses CHAR(1) with a value of either 'Y' or blank (i.e. '') to indicate true and false.

I'd rather have the column type as TINYINT with 1 to indicate true and 0 to indicate false. (Booleans--I want booleans.) I want this in part because PHP makes casting 1 and 0 to true and false a lot easier. 'Y' v. '' is going to require more logic than I'm happy with, and eventually someone will forget they're not actually booleans and cause a mess.

So far, this is my approach:

1. Add a new column to the table for each of the old columns I'm trying to get rid of.
2. Use MySQL's IF structure to populate my new (TINYINT) columns appropriately
3. Kill the old columns and rename the new columns in their place

The columns are acting as foreign keys anywhere, and I'm completely isolated for other systems, so no worries there. My question is two-fold:

Firstly, is this the best approach? It seems to me there may be a better way of doing this. Is it possible to change the values in the current column and then change its type without risking losing my data?

Secondly, if I am on the right track, how do I turn this `SELECT IF(strcmp(hardware.USER_HARDWARE_REQUEST, 'Y'), 0, 1) FROM hardware;` into an update to store that value in another column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I've got it. I can go ahead and update the Y/'' values to 1/0 and then simply change the type.

Query I ended up using looks something like this `UPDATE hardware SET SERVER_HARDWARE_REQUEST = (SELECT IF(strcmp(hardware.SERVER_HARDWARE_REQUEST, 'Y'), 0, 1));`

Then I can simply change the type definition for the column and it works like magic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` also :

```
SELECT 
    CASE hardware.USER_HARDWARE_REQUEST WHEN 'Y' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as 'result'     
FROM hardware;
```